# Send keys in VB6 not working on textbox

Tags: vb6, sendkeys

I have a webbrowser in VB6 that displays a web site from a third party company. I´m trying to paste text inside this website's textboxes with the code:

```
mainFrm.wbr(1).SetFocus
SendKeys "10"
```

It is working on most textboxes, except for one that has some keys disabled by the javascript funcion:

```
function only_numbers()
{
    var key=window.event.keycode;
    if (key < 48 || key > 57)
    {
        if(key != 44 || key != 8 || key != 46 || key != 96)
        {
            window.event.keycode=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to bypass this script? Or maybe another way of setting the text of the textbox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: get the instance of that browser, enum html objects, find the script node, delete it.

Comment: I tried it and the sendkeys command stopped working. In the end I solved it by getting the html id of the textbox and setting it's value from VB6. Your comment pointed me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use VB6 Desktop application where I work. Always avoid using "SendKeys" but the use, use as follows:

```
SendKeys "{DOWN}"
```

In other words, when using "{" and "}"

We also have a function called "SoNumeros" where it validates what the final User are typing and allows only numbers.

we always in action "KeyPress" component:

```
Function SoNumeros(KeyAscii, Optional Nao_Aceita_Virgula_ou_Ponto As Integer, Optional ByVal aceitaValoresNegativos As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal aceitaBarra As Boolean = False)
    If KeyAscii = Asc("-") And Not aceitaValoresNegativos Then KeyAscii = 0

    If Nao_Aceita_Virgula_ou_Ponto = 0 Then
        '        If Not (IsNumeric(Chr(KeyAscii))) And KeyAscii  8 And KeyAscii  Asc(",") And KeyAscii  Asc(".") And KeyAscii  Asc("-") Then
        If Not (IsNumeric(Chr(KeyAscii))) And KeyAscii  8 And KeyAscii  Asc(",") And KeyAscii  Asc("-") Then
            If aceitaBarra = False Then
                KeyAscii = 0
            Else
                If KeyAscii  Asc("/") Then
                    KeyAscii = 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If Not (IsNumeric(Chr(KeyAscii))) And KeyAscii  8 And KeyAscii  Asc("-") Then
            If aceitaBarra = False Then
                KeyAscii = 0
            Else
                If KeyAscii  Asc("/") Then
                    KeyAscii = 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

I hope it helped you